# Remember me auto login with JSF + JAAS

Tags: java, jsf, authentication, filter

I am trying to add *remember me* functionality to my app, but for some reason the  [HttpServletRequest.login()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is throwing a `ServletException`:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Login failed
at com.cleanup.filter.AutoLoginFilter.doFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:71)
```

Line 71:

```
req.login(adminUser.getEmail(), adminUser.getPwd());
```

I know that according to docs:

> **Throws**: ServletException - if the configured login mechanism does not
>   support username password authentication, or if a non-null caller
>   identity had already been established (prior to the call to login), or
>   if validation of the provided username and password fails.

Which in turn would mean that the credentials are "invalid" which is **not** true, since the log in mechanism works fine.

But why would it throw this exception then ?

My theory is that its due to the fact that the `password` is encrypted but if this is the case, shouldn't  `request.login(..,..)` also work with the already hashed password ?

Here's my filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {


    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    String remoteUser = (String) req.getRemoteUser();

    if (remoteUser == null) {

        String uuid = CookieRememberUtil.getCookieValue(req);

        System.out.println("Found cookie" + uuid);

        if (uuid != null) {
            AdminUsers adminUser = cookiesFacade.getAdminUserFromUUID(uuid);

            if (adminUser != null) {

                req.login(adminUser.getEmail(), adminUser.getPwd());
                CookieRememberUtil.addCookie(resp, uuid);
            } else {
                CookieRememberUtil.removeCookie(resp);
            }
        }

    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the underlying realm implementation that backs up your login process.

The login method inevitably defers to the configured Realm to do that actual authentication. For example, if you're using a DB Realm, the Realm will look up the user in the DB, compare the passwords, and then extract the role information.

So, what you need to do is to make your Realm "cookie aware".

That is, when you hit your filter, you can check for your "remember me" cookie, and basically pass that info in to the login method, so that it eventually arrives at your custom Realm, which then does the right thing.

```
String uuid = CookieRememberUtil.getCookieValue(req);
if (uuid != null) {
    req.login("***REMEMBER_ME***", uuid);
} else {
    ... run your normal login logic
}
```

The realm then looks for the magic user, who's name is "***REMEMBER_ME***", and uses the UUID extract the credentials, and build up the principal.

Then, as a rule, you disallow things like "*" from user names, that way it's more difficult for someone to login in and spam you with UUIDs to try and gain access. You check that during login, and simply abort with an invalid user name, user not found, etc.

So, TLDR, you need a custom realm for your container.

Edit:

In order for the container to perform authorization, it uses a concept called a Realm. A Realm is the piece of code that validates the user, checks their password, and loads up their roles by creating a Principal. All of the containers come with built in Realms that do basic things: work against a flat file, work against database, perhaps work against an LDAP server.

You can write a custom Realm implementation and install it within your container, it tends to be a pretty straightforward interface that you implement.

The ENTIRE PURPOSE of the Realm is to take credentials, and return a Principal. Using the programmatic login facility of Servlet 3.x, you get to chose not only when to make the login call, but what credentials to pass in to the Realm.

Normally, you pass in the user name and their password. The Realm looks up the user name, hashes the password, compares it to what's store, and voila, create a simple Principal and returns it.

In your case, when you have the REMEMBER_ME cookie set, rather than returning the user name and password (which you don't have, since you don't prompt for it), you return the cookie, or data you can extract from the cookie. But your only interface to the Realm, via the login method, accepts a username and a password. In truth, it accepts two strings, which can HAPPEN to be a user name and password. In truth, they can be any -- such as a flag tell the Realm to log in via a cookie value, and the associated cookie value.

The Realm uses the cookie value to look up the identity, and create an appropriate Principal. The Principal you return does not have to have the same "user name" as the first parameter to the login function, it can return any Principal it wants.

Comment: Not sure i understand you.